# How to create a SQL trigger for AS400 Table

Tags: sql, db2, database-trigger, db2-400

I'm a Java developer but not a RPG developer. For one of my project i need to create a SQL `AFTER INSERT` trigger for a `AS400` table (TABLE A) and copy that newly created row into the another table (TABLE B). Both table have the same structure. 
Really appreciate if someone can guide me to do the process. Please note i have fully authority to do any kind of process on AS400. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
AS400 is a IBM appliance that's contain a SQL Engine (DB2)

Comment: What you create until now?

Comment: @Krismorte I have already created the sql trigger. i want to add it to the As400 table.

Comment: just to be clear AS400 is the table's name? And which database are you working with?

Comment: @Krismorte AS400 is a IBM Server with SQL Engine so i can execute SQL statements as well.

Comment: @Krismorte It's DB2 but it'a also have the SQL engine too.

Comment: @Krismorte Thanks for improve the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IBM DB2 for i CREATE TRIGGER reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhctrigger.htm)

You have a few choices to make, **mode** and **granularity**

> MODE DB2SQL is valid for AFTER triggers. MODE DB2SQL AFTER triggers
>   are activated after all of the row operations have occurred.
>
> MODE DB2ROW triggers are activated on each row operation. MODE DB2ROW
>   is valid for both the BEFORE and AFTER activation time.
>
> FOR EACH ROW Specifies that the database manager executes the
>   triggered-action for each row of the subject table that the triggering
>   operation modifies. If the triggering operation does not modify any
>   rows, the triggered-action is not executed.
>
> FOR EACH STATEMENT Specifies that the database manager executes the
>   triggered-action only once for the triggering operation. Even if the
>   triggering operation does not modify or delete any rows, the triggered
>   action is still executed once. FOR EACH STATEMENT cannot be specified
>   for a BEFORE trigger. FOR EACH STATEMENT cannot be specified for a
>   MODE DB2ROW trigger.

The `REFERENCING` clause of the documentation has a nice table showing how they interact.

Assuming your original table is having multi-row insert done, then performance would benefit from having the trigger fire once per statement...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME AFTER INSERT
ON TABLE_A
  REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS TABLE_N 
  FOR EACH STATEMENT MODE DB2SQL

  begin atomic
    insert into TABLE_B 
      select * from TABLE_N;
  end
```

Alternate, row by row...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME AFTER INSERT
ON TABLE_A
  REFERENCING NEW ROW AS N 
  FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2ROW

  begin atomic
    insert into TABLE_B 
      values(n.col1, n.col2, n.col3, <....>);
  end
```

If only one row is being inserted into TABLE_A at a time, both statements will insert 1 row at a time into TABLE_B.

If 10 rows are inserted into TABLE_A with a single insert, the `FOR EACH STATEMENT MODE DB2SQL` will insert 10 rows at once into TABLE_B; whereas `FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2ROW` will do 10 separate inserts.

Sometimes, you have to use FOR EACH ROW, for example for BEFORE TRIGGERs.

But (generally) in SQL, you're better off doing set based operations whenever possible.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. I need to fire the trigger and insert record to `TABLE_B` every time `TABLE_A` got a new record. Can i do it with `FOR EACH STATEMENT`? And also can you tell me what is the `TABLE_N`?

Comment: If you're only inserting one row at a time, then `FOR EACH STATEMENT MODE DB2SQL` will only insert 1 row at a time into TABLE_B.  However, if you have multiple rows to insert, then you should insert them with 1 statement.  In which case, the above will insert them into TABLE_B in one shot.  TABLE_N is the set of rows inserted into TABLE_A by a single `INSERT`

Comment: Just for clarify, In my case so many programs separately inserting data to TABLE_A. Hope that not be a problem when using `FOR EACH STATEMENT MODE DB2SQ' ?

Comment: TABLE_N is temporary table or should i create it with the same table structure as TABLE_A and TABLE_B?

Comment: TABLE_N is built by the system, it will have the same columns as TABLE_A...

Comment: It's mean if i use `FOR EACH STATEMENT MODE DB2SQL` it's better for performance right?

Comment: @Dzshean, yes if you're inserting multiple rows with a single insert.  But I don't believe it will hurt if you end up just doing single rows...

Comment: @Chaeles Thank you so much for the explanation and samples. Finally can u tell me can i write this trigger using `ADDPFTRG` command ?

Comment: Can u tell me where should i put this SQL trigger statement to run? `STRSQL` is not accepting this trigger statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164199/discussion-between-charles-and-dzshean).

Comment: @Chaeles Trigger working ok on `Physical File`. Is there any changes when write trigger to a `Logical file`?

Comment: @Dzshean, completely different...ask a new question.

Comment: @Chaeles Thank you i'll post a new question. Another thing to clarify, is this the proper way to filter selected row `insert into TABLE_B 
      select * from TABLE_N where TABLE_N .column1 = 0 and ...`